# Chromium Password Manager NOT requiring password to view passwords

Tags: 16.04, unity, password, security, chromium

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and `chrome://settings/passwords` is what I'm talking about.

I was going there to check a password that I forgot, and to my surprise, clicking the Show Password button shows me the password without any authentication checks unlike on Windows.

Is there a way for to make it more secure somehow other than disabling it outright?

Comment: Well, Chromium stores passwords by default in your login keyring, which means they are stored on disk encrypted with your Ubuntu user account password, and unlocked automatically each time you log in. Is that secure enough, as they are not stored in plain text anywhere, or do you seek run-time protection with another password? In the latter case, you should probably use an external password manager extension for Chromium...

Comment: I know they're not stored in plain text, my problem is if I left my laptop unattended for a bit, anyone can open go through all my passwords.  
You said chromium uses the login keyring by default, is it possible to have it use another keyring for the password manager in particular?

Comment: @Machination Did You found the solution for that as I am also facing a similar problem

Comment: I stopped saving important passwords.